# How to retrieve the nth group of a number of elements

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I found that to select limited number of elements from the database `$x` I can use

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY id LIMIT $x";
```

so if $x=10 this query will retrieve the first 10 elements from the database.

But how can I retrieve the nth `$x` elements?

For example, if `$n=5` and `$x=20` I want to retrieve 20 elements so that the 20 elements be the 5th 20 elements from the database , for this example to be the elements from 80 - 100 in the database whatever was their ID.

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $entriesPerPage = 20; // Amount of results shown per page
    $activePage     = 5;  // The active page

    $offset = ($activePage - 1) * $entriesPerPage;
    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM `user` ORDER BY `id` LIMIT $offset, $entriesPerPage";
    // ...
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$m = $n-1;

$start = $m*$x;

$sql="SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY id LIMIT $start, $x";
```

Comment: The second argument of `LIMIT` represents the amount of results, not an offset.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY id LIMIT 80,20
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume we wish to select all records from 1 - 30 (inclusive) from a table called "Orders". The SQL query would then look like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 30";
```

When the SQL query above is run, it will return the first 30 records.

What if we want to select records 16 - 25 (inclusive)?

Mysql also provides a way to handle this: by using OFFSET.

The SQL query below says "return only 10 records, start on record 16 (OFFSET 15)":

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 10 OFFSET 15";
```

You could also use a shorter syntax to achieve the same result:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 15, 10";
```

Notice that the numbers are reversed when you use a comma.

Reference: [Click here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)